# Arrange the number

Tags: combinatorics

Consider this sequence {1, 2, 3 ... N}, as an initial sequence of first N natural numbers. You can rearrange this sequence in many ways. There will be a total of N! arrangements. You have to calculate the number of arrangement of first N natural numbers, where in first M positions; exactly K numbers are in their initial position.

```
 1. For Example, N = 5, M = 3, K = 2 , Answer is = 12.
 2. For Example, N = 10, M = 6, K = 3 , Answer is = 64320.
```

For N=5,M=3,K=2.... 
You should count this arrangement {1, 4, 3, 2, 5}, here in first 3 positions 1 is in 1st position and 3 in 3rd position. So exactly 2 of its first 3 are in there initial position.

But you should not count {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}.

Comment: What's the source of this problem, please?

Comment: I say, WHAT'S THE SOURCE OF THIS PROBLEM, PLEASE?

Comment: http://www.lightoj.com/volume_showproblem.php?problem=1095

Comment: Thanks. But that site requires a login. Though it makes it clear that the problem is from a Bangladeshi contest. You're not trying to cheat in an ongoing competition, are you?

Comment: this an online judge platform not arena.

Comment: I don't know what that means. But if you want to be sure I see a comment meant for me, you have to include @Gerry in it somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*M* and *K* define the number of possible combinations of fixed positions, what is $\binom{M}{K}$.

Now we have a string with two kind of positions: free positions where any number can appear, i.e. $N-M$ positions, and the positions $M-K$ where some number is prohibited.

Using the principle of inclusion-exclusion we have that the valid permutations are

$$\sum_{j=0}^{M-K}(-1)^j\binom{M-K}{j}(N-K-j)!=(N-K)!\ _1F_1(K-M;K-N;-1)$$

what doesnt have a closed form.

Then for every $N,M,K$ the solutions will be

$$\binom{M}{K}(N-K)!\ _1F_1(K-M;K-N;-1)$$

May exist some kind of closed solutions? I dont know how by now :(

Comment: What is F1 ?@masacroso

Comment: @DurontoHabib it is a hypergeometric function named [confluent hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function)

Comment: It will be helpful for me, if you are not bored to explain a ans For `N=10, M=6 and K= 3`